# Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 176. Encountered: " " (32), after : "BIND"

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena

I am getting `Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 176.  Encountered: " " (32), after: "BIND"` error while running below query using Jena,

```
String queryString = "PREFIX  ns:  <http://example.org/ns#>" + 
                "SELECT  ?title ?price" + 
                "  {" + 
                "    ?x ns:price ?p ." + 
                "    ?x ns:discount ?discount ." + 
                "    ?x <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?title . " + 
                "    BIND ('12'^^xsd:integer AS ?price)" + 
                "    FILTER( ?price < 20 )" + 
                "  }";
```

Below is my stack trace,

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 176.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "BIND"
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL10.perform(ParserSPARQL10.java:95)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL10.parse(ParserSPARQL10.java:39)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:129)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:72)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:43)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:31)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(QueryExecutionFactory.java:342)
    at com.ifour.testdata.AW317.QuerySampleDataSPARQL.main(QuerySampleDataSPARQL.java:28)
```

can anybody please help me on an issue I have googled but didn't find the solution.The same query runs on virtuoso SPARQL endpoint giving me perfect result.but while using java Jena SPARQL query I am getting this error.

Comment: Old Jena version ... `com.hp.hpl.jena.query` indicates version 2.x which needs special parse flag to handle SPARQL 1.1. Please update to latest Jena 3.6.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AKSW.Yup you are right.It's solved my problem.

Comment: I suppose, [`LET`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/assignment.html) should work in Jena2. This is a possible workaround, if the problem is in `BIND`.

Comment: The workaround would be to use `QueryFactory.create(queryStr, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL_11)` and pass this to `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(...`

Comment: `ParserSPARQL10`: This is an old version of Jena where the default query language is SPARQL 1.0. That's really quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments by @AKSW, the answer is to

Update to [current Jena](https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi) (and possibly current Virtuoso server [whether [Enterprise](https://shop.openlinksw.com/license_generator/virtuoso/) or [Open Source](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload)], [Virtuoso Provider for Jena, and/or Virtuoso JDBC driver](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider))